# Creating .desktop files for wine applications

Tags: unity, wine, launcher

I have two different wine apps I want to place and run from Ubuntu's 14.04 launcher. For both I've created their own .desktop files and added both to the launcher. Icons look good, both are clickable and start the wine app. However as soon as wine app is started - it is not appearing under the clicked icon - it creates completely new icon with wine's standard red glass.

So my question is how to prevent wine's standard icon appearing with started process and use the clicked icon instead.

Here's the .desktop file for Photoshop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Photoshop CS6
Exec=wine "C:\Program Files\Photoshop\photoshop.exe"
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/xxx/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Photoshop/
Icon=907A_Photoshop.0
StartupWMClass=Photoshop.exe
Terminal=false
```

And here's .desktop file for another app:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SQLyog - 32 bit
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/xxx/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/xxx/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/SQLyog\\ -\\ 32\\ bit.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/xxx/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/SQLyog
Icon=7005_SQLyog.0
StartupWMClass=SQLyog.exe
Terminal=false
```

And even worse, in Docky when both apps started - both appear under Photoshop icon.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You already seem to know that you need to specify the window class in the .desktop file for the program to be grouped correctly. Since it does not get grouped correctly, these probably don't match. To find out the window class of your running application, do the following:
- Start the application
- start a terminal
- run "xprop" in the terminal
- click on the program's window

You now get the window's properties printed in the terminal. Near the bottom should be a line "WM_CLASS". It contains one or more Strings, which are the window classes assigned to your program's window. Try to find one that is unique for your window (Wine applications seem to have "Wine" as one window class, which probably causes your windows to appear with the Wine icon, so take the other one if there is one). Use this String (only one, not both of them) in the StartupWMClass property of your .desktop file.

If you already did exactly that, I'm afraid I can't help you...